# Ping from a network namespace to another EC2 instance not working without NAT rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routing, bridge, network-namespace

I have the below setup.

I have setup two EC2 instances. I have added the security group rules on both machine to allow ICMP traffic and both can ping each other.

On one machine I have created two network namespaces `blue` and `red`. On this machine I have also setup a virtual switch using a bridge interface named `v-net-0` and connected the namespaces to it. I have respectively assigned `192.168.15.2` and `192.168.15.3` to blue and red namespaces.

I have assigned `192.168.15.5` to the `v-net-0`, so I can ping from the first instance to the namespaces. Then I issued, `ping 192.168.15.2` and `ping 192.168.15.3` to ping blue and red namespaces. It is working successfully.

Now I needed to ping the second instance from my blue namespace. So, I added a route table entry in the blue namespace using the command, `ip netns exec blue ip route add 172.31.80.0/20 via 192.168.15.5`. Also, I enabled ip forwarding on the first machine and added a NAT rule using the command, `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.15.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`.

Then I issued `ip netns exec blue ping 172.31.94.241`. So, as expected everything worked successfully.

So, as per my understand, we needed the NAT rule in the first machine to indicate to the second machine that the traffic is coming from the first machine's ip address. please correct me if I'm wrong.

The question I have is, can I ping the second machine from the blue namespace, without adding the NAT rule. My idea is if we add a routing entry in the second machine, with the destination to be `192.168.15.0/24`, the blue namespace might be able to ping the second machine without NAT. I tried this but didn't work.

Or is NAT required for this task?

Aprreciate any clarification and a solution!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all of your analysis is correct, I suspect the problem is in the details. If your namespace has `ip route add 172.31.80.0/20 via 192.168.15.5` and your second EC2 instance has `ip route add 192.168.15.0/24 via 172.31.X.Y` (adding in the IP address of your first EC2 instance), and IP forwarding is enabled on the first instance, you should be all set.

Since you mentioned setting up rules to allow the instances to ping eachother, my suspicion is that firewall is blocking your pings, either because you haven't allowed the `192.168.15.0/24` subnet, or because the EC2 architecture actually doesn't allow other subnets on that link for some reason.

For debugging I would recommend running `tcpdump icmp` on the 2 instances, to see how far the ping requests are getting, and if any replies are being generated. You could also do the same thing but send pings from the second instances to the namespace on the first instance, to see if the requests even make it to the first instance. Good luck!

Comment: I agree with your suggestion that the EC2 isn't allowing the ping from the private IP addresses (like 192.168.x.x) to be directly routed outside the VPC. I double checked the security group rules, it allows the ping from anywhere (`0.0.0.0/0`). So, I guess your observation is the answer.

Comment: @thunderbolt do the pings go through if you just add 192.168.X.X addresses to the interfaces and try to make them talk directly?

Comment: I did some more testing and all but confirmed this, but if anyone has some documentation that would be really nice. If you really want to have communication between instances without NAT for some reason, you could try wireguard or some other overlay network

Comment: I tried the internal communication between the interfaces of the network namespaces within the same EC2 instance. The pings worked successfully within the same machine. The issue is within communication between two EC2 instances. I think the EC2 arch doesn't allow such communication aside without using NAT. But better to have some documentation for more visibility.

Comment: @thunderbolt yeah spot on, I did some testing and came to the same conclusion, and it makes perfect sense they'd design it that way, but I think for a high quality answer we'd want some documentation to point to

Comment: Or for all I know this is widespread standard practice 